# Best search ways in comma separated values for comma separated option

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have user tables which contains column city_id and inside this column city ids are stored as comma separated values as following:

```
user_id  user_name     city_id    
1        abc1           1,2,3
2        abc2           15,2,9
3        abc5           1,2,13
```

Now I want to search rows which contains city id = `1,9,13` from city_id column.

How it can be done?

Expected Ouput:

```
abc, abc1, abc3
```

Comment: Don't store the data like that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid storing CSV data in the `city_id` column as you are currently doing.  Ideally, one record should have just one data point for `city_id`.  That being said, MySQL offers a function `FIND_IN_SET` which can cope with CSV data, at least to a point.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT user_name
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET('1', city_id) > 0 OR
    FIND_IN_SET('9', city_id) > 0 OR
    FIND_IN_SET('13', city_id) > 0;
```

We can make the query even tighter by using `REGEXP` with the regex alternation `\b(1|9|13)\b`:

```
SELECT user_name
FROM yourTable
WHERE city_id REGEXP '[[:<:]](1|9|13)[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: (As a note, `[[:<:]]` is the leading POSIX equivalent of `\b` and  `[[:>:]]` is the closing. MySQL uses POSIX, not PCRE, so regexs need to be modified accordingly.)